# How to kill running app in Leksah?

Tags: haskell, leksah

When I run a server app in Leksah using `Run the package` command, I'm not able to stop the new process from the IDE. I have to kill it in terminal by PID. Can I do it in Leksah?

Comment: Opened [issue](https://github.com/leksah/leksah/issues/270)